# Can I set the block size in genesis block by puppeth?

Tags: private-blockchain, blocks

Found the block size is set to 30K in genesis block. How can I modify this value to 100K or 1M by puppeth?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To increase block size you have to increase the gasLimit of a block so that more transaction can be included in block, ultimately block size increase.